# Python package naming issue

Tags: python

I have a python package named gutils, which contains a lot of useful tools for development, some of them are generic, some of them use reportlabs and the most important part forms a layer of abstraction on top of django, customizing a lot of default behaviour

I would like to keep the convention of the exterior interface similar to django's, as to not add complexity to the development proccess..

I have this structure (as an example):

```
    gutils
      |---- django
              |
              |----forms
                     |
                     |---widgets.py
```

The problem is, inside this widgets.py file, the imports resolve to the current subpackage.
For example:

```
from django.forms import TextInput
```

Is treated as if it were:

```
from gutils.django.forms import TextInput
```

As a workaround, I've named the top-level package gdjango, but it looks awkward.

So, the question is:

Is there a way to reference the real django package from within the gutils.django package?

**NOTE:** I'm using python 3

Comment: where is your TextInput located and where is the default one located?

Comment: from __future__ import absolute_import and add the parent dir of gutils to the PYTHONPATH

Comment: @user3885927 I don't have a TextInput.. the default one is in the django package

Comment: @Meitham I'm using python 3.. should I use future?

Comment: Absolute import is the default in python 3. Just ensure your PYTHONPATH does not include gutils, only its parent.

Comment: It isn't included... but maybe I just messed up my virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with a package, for example, like this:

```
mypackage /
    mypackagesubdir /
        myfile.py
    mypackagesubdirII /
        myfileII.py
```

and you're editting `myfile.py`, import `myfileII` like `import .mypackagessubdirII.myfileII`. `.` means the root of the package.